# (Excel bug?) Avoid Hyperlink hit-area repeating on all pages of PDF generated with Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I discovered something strange in a PDF generated with Excel 2007. I need to create TextBoxes with Hyperlinks on a worksheet, set repeating header rows for printing and then export the worksheet to PDF.

Here's what happens. The first page of the PDF will show the TextBox, and it is clickable as a link, as expected. But strangely, all the *following pages* will have an area that's also *clickable* in about the same place the *first page* has the TextBox, but there's absolutely nothing there - i.e. second page is visibly blank, but there is somewhere on the page a blank *clickable* area that will open up the link of the TextBox from the first page. Which is **not** desired.

Here's some code that will prepare the scenario exactly:

```
    ' Run this procedure
Public Sub TestRepeatingHyperlinkHitArea()
    Call AddDummyContent
    Call CreateTextBoxWithHyperlink

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Address
    Call ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(xlTypePDF, _
        "RepeatingHyperlinkHitArea.pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True)
End Sub

Public Sub AddDummyContent()
    ' Needed only to create multiple pages
    Call ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 300
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = i
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub CreateTextBoxWithHyperlink()
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count = 1 Then
        Call ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Delete
    End If

    Dim TB As Shape
    Set TB = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _ 
        100, 100, 150, 50)
    TB.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "I'm a textbox with a hyperlink"
    Call ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(TB, "http://www.example.com")
End Sub
```

Paste this in a blank Workbook and run `TestRepeatingHyperlinkHitArea()`. It will prepare the `ActiveSheet` and create a PDF. In the PDF, search with your mouse on the second page and in its first half there will be the hit-area of a link (the same link from page 1), but nothing visible.

Is this avoidable? I really don't want ghost-links on the pages. It only seems to happen when `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows` is set, and only Hyperlinks on the first page are repeated as ghost-links. I'm assuming that the hyperlink hit-areas are somehow rendered on the same layer as the PrintTitleRows. Which is bad, as they get repeated together in the PDF.

Instead of normal TextBoxes, I tried using ActiveX Labels as Hyperlinks, since they don't exhibit this problem (they don't get rendered as Shapes?), but they're a mess to set up as Hyperlink targets in VBA (calling `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add()` on an ActiveX Label fails with error, no matter how I try to convert them to Shapes). Still trying though.

Any ideas about creating Hyperlinks in a PDF with repeating header rows are welcome.

**EDIT**: Dropbox link to generated PDF file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/un1q81vgpvvg6w0/RepeatingHyperlinkHitArea.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Can you test the code That I posted below in Excel 2007? If the problem still persists then I will delete my answer and try and test it in excel 2007.

Comment: Ok I have deleted the answer. Let me get a copy of excel 2007 for testing. You can upload the pdf in any free file sharing site and then share the link here

Comment: Uploaded on Dropbox, link is in question text. I opened the PDF file with Okular too (PDF Viewer of KDE on Linux) and it shows the same symptoms - blank second page, but clickable area as link, just like the TextBox on the first page.

Comment: Yeah I can see that in the pdf file. I will have to test it in Excel 2007

Comment: Will also try to get to a computer running Excel 2010 and try this. Thanks!